# This is in the company requirement list, I want to know the difference between them

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

what is the difference between spring core, spring boot, and spring MVC?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Simple terms,

1. ***Spring MVC***

   **Spring** - It is a Inversion of control (IOC) and Dependency Injection (DI) framework. Spring helps you develop enterprise applications. Most information you can read here https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework

   **MVC** - It is a design pattern (Model - View - Controller ) MVC , by definition, they are proven patterns and methods to design your application well. We have several design patterns such as `Singleton, Factory pattern etc` Read more about it here https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns
2. ***Spring-boot*** - It is a library built on top of Spring framework (like we have JARs)  which helps develop production ready quick service oriented applications. You can still use typical Spring features. Read more about it here https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot
3. **Spring-core** - Just a named terminology representing core features of Spring framework such as `IOC container, Dependency Injection, Bean scopes, Autowiring` etc

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I want to become a full-stack developer which is best suited?

Comment: Full stack consists of `Front end` which includes scripting and programming languages like `HTML,CSS,JavaScript, JQuery, Angular etc` plus `Back end` which consists of server side programming languages such as `C#, VB.NET, Java` etc,  So to answer your question, you need both , but `Spring, .NET , Django` etc are `frameworks` which allow you to code in `Java, C#/VB, Python` Respectively ! I suggest you understand basics of Client server technologies but hope this answers the question